# How to populate DropDownList in GridView edititemtemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a weird problem which i can't find an answer to.
I have a GridView with some ItemTemplate and also two DropDownLists inside 2 seperate EditItemTemplates.

They both look the same but only one is being recognized in page load while the other is not and i'm getting an error: "the name does not exist in the current context"

I want to populate both DropDownLists with data from DB and make SelectedValue to be as the value of the Label.
HallsDDL works ok , the second one doesn't.

I saw some similar issues on Google but couldn't find an answer for that.

My aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" Font-Size = "13pt" RowStyle-CssClass="cssWidth"  HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
  AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE"
  OnPageIndexChanging="myGridView_PageIndexChanging"
OnSorting="myGridView_Sorting"
  onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelling"
  onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing"
  onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"  OnRowDataBound = "RowDataBound">

  <Columns>           
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="מזהה">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton PostBackUrl='<%# "~/Events_workers.aspx?RowIndex=" + Container.DataItemIndex %>' runat="server" ID="Order_Id" Text='<%#Eval("Order_Id")%>' CssClass="cssWidth"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="שם פרטי" SortExpression="First_Name" >

        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="First_Name" Text='<%#Eval("First_Name") %>' CssClass="cssWidth"/>
        </ItemTemplate>


     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="שם משפחה" SortExpression="Last_Name">

        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Last_Name" Text='<%#Eval("Last_Name") %>' CssClass="cssWidth"/>
        </ItemTemplate>



     </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="תאריך אירוע">

       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="EventDate" Text='<%#Eval("EventDate") %>' CssClass="cssWidth" />
       </ItemTemplate>

       <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="cssWidth" ID="txtDate" Text='<%#Eval("EventDate") %>' MaxLength="15" onkeypress='validate(event)' />
         </EditItemTemplate>

      </asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="אולם">

       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="HallName" Text='<%#Eval("HallName") %>' CssClass="cssWidth" />
       </ItemTemplate>

      <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="HallName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HallName")%>' Visible = "false"></asp:Label>
         <asp:DropDownList  ID="HallsDDL" runat="server" CssClass="cssWidth"></asp:DropDownList>
         </EditItemTemplate>

      </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="סוג אירוע">

       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Event_Name" Text='<%#Eval("Event_Name") %>' CssClass="cssWidth" />
       </ItemTemplate>



      </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="תפריט">

       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label  ID="Menu_Name" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("Menu_Name") %>' CssClass="cssWidth" />
       </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Menu_Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Menu_Name")%>' Visible = "false"></asp:Label>
         <asp:DropDownList  ID="menuDDL" runat="server" CssClass="cssWidth" ></asp:DropDownList>
         </EditItemTemplate>


      </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="כמות אורחים"  SortExpression="Guest_Amount">

       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Guest_Amount" Text='<%#Eval("Guest_Amount") %>' CssClass="cssWidth" />
       </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="cssWidth" ID="txtAGuest_Amount" Text='<%#Eval("Guest_Amount") %>' />
         </EditItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>


  <asp:TemplateField>

  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" Text="ערוך" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
  </ItemTemplate>


  <EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" Text="עדכן" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="בטל" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
  </EditItemTemplate>

  </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField>

  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete"  Text="בטל אירוע" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteRecord" CausesValidation="False"
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Order_Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>

</ItemTemplate>

  </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = ("dd/MM/yyyy");
    culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    dal.check_orders_date();
    /* if (Session["admin"] == null)
     {
         Response.Redirect("Admin_Login.aspx");
     }*/
    string state = (string)ViewState["state"];
    name.Text = "אירועים עתידיים:";
    DataTable Halls = new DataTable();
    DataTable Menus = new DataTable();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {


        Halls = dal.get_halls();
        hallsDDL.DataSource = Halls;
        hallsDDL.DataValueField = "HallName";
        hallsDDL.DataBind();
        Menus = dal.get_Menus();
        //menuDDL.DataSource = Menus;
        //menuDDL.DataValueField = "Menu_Name";
        //menuDDL.DataBind();

        if (state != "edit" || ViewState["myDataTable"] == null)
        {
            BindGridData();
        }
    }

    if (Request.QueryString["fname"] == null && Request.QueryString    ["lname"] == null && Request.QueryString["fdate"] == null && Request.QueryString["tdate"] == null && Request.QueryString["hall_id"] != null)
    {

        System.Data.DataTable ds = dal.Get_orders_by_hall(Convert.ToInt32  (Request.QueryString["hall_id"]));

        SetViewState(ds);
        gv.DataSource = ds;
        gv.DataBind();

    }

}
```

In code behind hallsDDL is recognized while menuDDL doesn't exist.
I checked and rechecked everything but i can't seem to find the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I'm surprised that `hallsDDL` is showing up in the code-behind.  Do you have another `DropDownList`, outside the `GridView`, that is also called `hallsDDL`?

Controls defined in templates in templated controls like `GridView` are not class-level fields the way the `GridView` itself is, or the way a `DropDownList` positioned outside the `GridView` would be.  The page doesn't "know" about them, because they're internal to the `GridView`.  They don't even exist until after the `GridView` itself is bound.

That's why people typically bind dropdowns and other bindable controls in row-level events, such as `RowEditing` or `RowDataBound`.  Those events give you a reference to the specific row in their event arguments, and allow you to access the controls in the row through the `FindControl` method.

For several examples of doing this, you can look at this question and answer:  [How do you bind a DropDownList in a GridView in the EditItemTemplate Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172175/how-do-you-bind-a-dropdownlist-in-a-gridview-in-the-edititemtemplate-field?rq=1).

Comment: it was all just a big mixup regarding names and binding sources.
it's working ok now , thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are supposedly initializing in Page_Load.

It is **correct** that you **cannot** reference menuDDL

It is absolutely **incorrect** that you **can** reference HallsDDL.

It must exist elsewhere in your code for it to be available in Page_Load.  You cannot reference an embedded  GridView row-based control without a call to `FindControl()`, typically e.Row.FindControl() or maybe using a ForEach with GridView.Rows().

I suggest you check the page markup for a rogue asp:DropDownList definiton